# Editable AngularJS Input Filter

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, filter, angularjs-filter

I've got an array of objects loaded into an ng-repeated list. That list is filtered based on the value entered in an input field just above it when a user clicks the 'filter' button. That works fine. However, I also want a select dropdown next to the input to edit the effects of the input filter.

*In other words, the way the filter handles the value in the input field should change based on what option is selected in the dropdown next to it.*

Here's the code:

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-app="programApp" ng-controller="programController">
  <label>Name: 
    <select>
      <option>Contains</option>
      <option>Equals</option>
      <option>Starts with</option>
      <option>Ends with</option>
      <option>Does not contain</option>
    </select>
    <input ng-model="nameField" type="text">
  </label>
  <button ng-click="runFilter()">Filter</button>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="name in names | filter:filterNameField">{{name.name}}, <i>{{name.age}}</i></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**Angular:**

```
angular.module('programApp', [
    'programApp.controllers',
]);
angular.module('programApp.controllers', [])
    .controller('programController', ['$scope', '$filter', '$http', 
    function($scope, $filter, $http){

      $scope.names = [{
            'name':'Fred',
            'age':'35 years'
        },{
            'name':'Alberta',
            'age':'46 years'
        },{
            'name':'Francis',
            'age':'31 years'
        },{
            'name':'Sarah',
            'age':'12 years'
        },{
            'name':'Matthew',
            'age':'16 years'
        },{
            'name':'Tracy',
            'age':'87 years'
        },{
            'name':'Jordan',
            'age':'35 years'
        },{
            'name':'Sam',
            'age':'26 years'
        },{
            'name':'Mason',
            'age':'38 years'
        },{
            'name':'Travis',
            'age':'11 years'
        },{
            'name':'Corey',
            'age': '86 years'
        },{
            'name':'Andrew',
            'age':'55 years'
        },{
            'name':'John',
            'age':'66 years'
        },{
            'name':'Jack',
            'age':'73 years'
        }];

      $scope.runFilter = function(){
        $scope.filterNameField = $scope.nameField;
      };

    }]);
```

So, if `Starts with` is selected, I want the input to filter by `start with`, and if `equals` is selected, only results matching the input exactly should be shown, and so on with the other options. How do I do this?

*See equivalent Codepen [here](http://codepen.io/trueScript/pen/aOvgvd).*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to create your own $filter and have it pass in the way you want it filtered:

HTML:

```
<li ng-repeat="name in names | myFilter:filterNameField:filterType">{{name.name}}, <i>{{name.age}}</i></li>
```

Javascript:

```
.$filter(function(){
    return function(input, name, type){
        //return based on name/type
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For strict comparaison you can use filter in html like this:

```
{{filterExpression | filter: stringToCompare: true}}
```

And for startwith comparaison you just have to make a function like this:

```
function(array,stringToCompare){
  if(array.startWith(stringToCompare) ==true) 
      Return whatYouNeed
};
```